# Change contrast in Camera Preview - Android

Tags: android, android-camera

It is possible change the contrast in the Camera preview in Android? I have been searching how to do It but I only see how to change the contrast in images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods for controlling white balance and exposure, directly controlling contrast is not availble until and unless you use 3rd party libraries. Most recognized is [OPENCV for Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html)

Here are the two methods, which can be passed as camera parameters

```
setWhiteBalance() or setExposureCompensation()
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with exposure compensation and white balance you can actually set **contrast** parameter itself. Check for the parameter "contrast" support in camera parameters flattened array and based on that you can make a decision. Below is one such example,

```
    Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
    String parmListStr = camParams.flatten();
    String[] parms = parmListStr.split(";");
    int maxContrast = 0, curContrast = 0, newContrast = 0;
    for(String str:parms){
        if(str.contains("max-contrast=")){
            String[] values = str.split("=");
            maxContrast = Integer.getInteger(values[1]);
        } else if (str.contains("contrast=")){
            String[] values = str.split("=");
            curContrast = Integer.getInteger(values[1]);
        }
    }

    if (maxContrast > 0 && curContrast >= 0){
        //calculate contrast as per your needs and set it to camera parameters as below
        newContrast = (curContrast + 1) < maxContrast? (curContrast + 1): maxContrast;
        camParams.set("contrast", newContrast);
        mCamera.setParameters(camParams);
    }
```

In the above example "contrast" and "max-contrast" are the camera parameter keys(from nexus4). These are not standard and they may change from one device to another. But as per my observation these are the common keys all manufacturers use. May be you can do more research about different devices to finalize on complete set of keys and write a logic based on that.